# SQL: String column to unique integer?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `place2022` which has a very long `CHAR` column

```
    timestamp    |                                         user_id                                          | pixel_color | coordinate 
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------
 17:38:20.021+00 | p0sXpmkcmg1KLiCdK5e4xKdudb1f8cjscGs35082sKpGBfQIw92nZ7yGvWbQ/ggB1+kkRBaYu1zy6n16yL/yjA== | #FF4500     | 371,488
 17:38:20.024+00 | Ctar52ln5JEpXT+tVVc8BtQwm1tPjRwPZmPvuamzsZDlFDkeo3+ItUW89J1rXDDeho6A4zCob1MKmJrzYAjipg== | #51E9F4     | 457,493
 17:38:20.025+00 | rNMF5wpFYT2RAItySLf9IcFZwOhczQhkRhmTD4gv0K78DpieXrVUw8T/MBAZjj2BIS8h5exPISQ4vlyzLzad5w== | #000000     | 65,986
 17:38:20.025+00 | u0a7l8hHVvncqYmav27EARAE6ciLtpUTPXMI33lDrUmtj5Ei3ixlfRuG28KUvs7r5LpeiE/iOKPALVjkILhrYg== | #3690EA     | 73,961
```

The `user_id`s are already hashes, so all I really care about here is having *some* sort of `id` column which is 1-1 with the `user_id`.

I've counted the number of unique `user_id`s, which is `10381163`, which fits into 24 bits. Therefore, I can compress the `id` field down to a 32-bit integer using the obvious scheme of "Assign 1 to the first new user_id you see, 2 to the second new user_id you see", etc. I don't even care that the user_id's are mapped in the order that they're seen: I just need them to be mapped in an invertible manner to 32-bit ints *somehow*. I'd also like to persist this mapping somewhere so that, if I want to, I can go backwards.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I imagine that we could create a new table (`create table place2022_user_ids as select distinct(user_id) from place2022;`?) and then reverse-lookup the `user_id` column in that table, but I don't know quite how to formulate the queries and also make sure that I'm not doing something ridiculously slow.

I am using postgresql, if it matters.

Comment: Don't make your life harder than it has to be. Leave the `user_id` as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent (>8) version of Postgres you can add an auto increment id column to an existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE place2022 
ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

NB If the existing column is a PRIMARY KEY you will need to drop it first.
See [drop primary key constraint in postgresql by knowing schema and table name only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962406/drop-primary-key-constraint-in-postgresql-by-knowing-schema-and-table-name-only)